# Magento marketplace with vendor payment

Tags: magento, paypal-adaptive-payments, marketplace

I'm using marketplace extension from magentoconnect in my store. This extension is really good and works exactly what i needed it to do but there is 1 particular requirement I need which it doesn't provide.

For vendors, I want payments of each product sale to go directly to vendor's account ( through their credit card etc which they need to add before their product becomes visible ) and commission amount ( some percentage which is set by marketplace through admin panel ) to go to site owner's account. I know there is paypal adaptive payment add-on available with this extension but I don't want to use paypal due to some reasons.

I have tried to create my own module which will gather vendor's payment method after their login and will verify it if their credentials are working or not. But i'm confused as to which approach should i use to get their order payment to go directly in vendor's account and commission in site owner's account right away.

Also, i want to use authorize.net to charge clients as stripe does not support a lot of countries.

Any help in right direction is very much appreciated. I need a solution as to how i can implement it. I can customize or create my own module if needed be for this particular case, but i need to know which is a better approach or what will be close to magento way of doing stuff.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks In Advance
Ab.M

Comment: I really need some hint as to which approach suits best. Experts please post some thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Regarding Paypal adaptive payment this thread will help https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/Adaptive-Payments-for-Magento-marketplace/td-p/968101

as authorize.net does not provide marketplace api like stripe or paypal provides so it wouldnt be possible in this way .

PS - we are not self promoting our plugin or product , as user asked the questions specifically about our product that why i have added extension link with images and screenshot