# How to manage multi-vendor PayPal transactions with service fee for my site?

Tags: paypal, parallel-processing, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

- My web application is a multi-vendor marketplace service
- PayPal requires that the vendors are the primary recipient for chargeback reasons
- My company collects a service fee % from the vendor for each sale
- **There can be several vendors in one client purchase**
- Chained payments only allow one primary recipient
- Parallel payments require that I expose the buyer to the service fee. For example, if I show an item for sale for $11 on the site, in PayPal's transaction interface, the buyer then must actually purchase a $9.90 item from the vendor plus a service fee of $1.10 from my company.
- I have read that Etsy does not have this problem in their PayPal interface.
- I have read that several Wordpress and Joomla shopping cart plugins handle this same issue without the buyer confusion
- I see many questions about this on SO, but none with a good solution.
- What is the preferred method to process multi-vendor marketplace transactions on PayPal?

Here are some SO similars that didn't help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465652/multivendor-site-using-paypal-adaptive-with-parallel-payment-show-only-product

[Paypal Adaptive Payments- Parallel or Chained for my multi vendor market place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156320/paypal-adaptive-payments-parallel-or-chained-for-my-multi-vendor-market-place)

Comment: Hey - have you been able to resolve this? Can you point me to solution? Im working on site with similar model and we need to use PayPal, but its not clear how to collect the platform fee on Pararell Payment (payment with multiple recipients)